# Proof that a field that is a monotone class is a sigma field

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I do not know how to convert a random sequence An to a increasing sequence with the same union. Usually I construct an increasing sequence from a random sequence like this:

$$
B_{i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{i}A_{j}
$$

However, as `i` goes to infinity, Bi no longer belongs to the field in order to prove the sigma additivity. Really appreciate any help

Monotone class, just in case: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m420/monotone.pdf

Comment: I do not understand your notation. On the right hand side of the displayed equation $i$ is used both as a variable (in $A_i$) and as a constant (the upper limit of the union).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the notation

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "as $i$ goes to infinity, $B_i$ no longer belongs to the field". First of all, what field, there is no mention of a field in the preceding lines. Second, $i$ is always finite. You defined $B_0,B_1,\dots$. Not sure what you are trying to say there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume the term "field" here is the same as "algebra")

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a field and a monotone class.
Given $(A_n)_{n \geq 1} \subset \mathcal{A}$, we can define $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_n = B_{n-1} \cup A_n$ for $n > 1$. Then, $\cup_{n \geq 1} A_n = \cup_{n \geq 1}B_n \in \mathcal{A}$ and hence $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: How can you know $B_{n}$ still belongs to the field when n goes to infinity?

Comment: By the definition of monotone class (note that $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \cdots$). I am not invoking any of the field properties to ensure the membership of $\cup_{n \geq 1} B_n$.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood the question. Thanks